# What will happen if I remove res.end() when creating a server in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm learning to create a simple server with NodeJS. Here is the code I extracted from my material:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end();
});

server.listen(3000);
```

What does `res.end()` do in this example? Must I use `res.end()` everytime I create a server? What will happen behind if I remove `res.end()` from the code above?

(I've tried removing `res.end()` from the code, run it, and what I see was the browser kept loading continously without showing anything (even the white blank page). I have no ideas what is happening behind)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try it and see....I believe what you are doing with each write instruction is putting data into the stream, but it will only be written once you either close the stream, flush It or call end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's break your code line by line

> var http = require('http');

This is to import `http` library from node.js in built libraries. Which can be used to do `http` related tasks. Creating server is one of that task.

> ```
> var server = http.createServer(fn).
> server.listen(3000);
> ```

`server.listen(3000)` will start a `http` server which will listen for `http` requests coming at `localhost:3000`. Each time your hit this address in your browser, `fn` function will be executed. No matter what route you hit. `fn` will be executed for `localhost:3000` as well as for `localhost:3000/anything/else`

> ```
> function(req, res){
>   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
>   res.end();
> }
> ```

When this function is executed when you hit `localhost:3000` in your browser, two `objects` request(`req`) and response(`res`) are suppled to this function via `http` library. `req` contains all the data related to request like URL, Body, etc. Response contains methods that you can use to build your response that is passed to the client or browser (who have initiated the request).

> ```
> res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
> res.end();
> ```

Here first, header is written into response then it is notified to `http` via `res.end()` that we have finished writing the response, please send it to the client. Please note, once you have end writing the response, you can write anything else in your response.

Regarding removing the `res.end()` you have already answered your question that browser kept loading. In actual, browser is waiting for a response from the server. If you will remove `res.end()`, server will not be able to notify client that response writing is done.

Comment: Only the last paragraph here is needed to answer the question.  Not sure why you made it harder to see the actual answer by putting all the other stuff in front of it.

Comment: I guess, OP is learning Node.js and I should give him some understanding about `http`

Comment: @Vipin Kumar Thank you very much for your answer. I'm fully satisfied with it. So according to your answer, `res.end()` means sending the response (including header + extra text/data/etc) to the client as well as inform the server that the response is complete, is it right?

Comment: Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 1):

> res.send()

Is sending a response to the client. If you are not sending a response back to the client you will not recieve any answer to render in your browser.

You have to send a response to the client from every route you specify. In your example the function you are passing to the `createServer()` method gets executed when the root address of your server is called. If you run this locally this would be `localhost:3000`